# Windows kernel driver development environment

Tags: windows, driver, development-environment

I am a total noob for windows driver development and recently I am assigned a project to develop drivers for windows 10 and 8.1

I have a PC with windows 8.1 and visual studio 2017. I have WinDbg. I have tried to do local debugging but I was not successful and somewhere it was recommended not to do it as its very limiting.

What would be the best setup to do kernel driver development with least hassle.

Does Os loader works in windows 8.1?

What are the things I need to keep in my mind before advancing?

Can I use windows 7 as a target, and develop and debug drivers for windows 10? On [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f446de0e-e18f-45ff-8add-ed0a428d2762/wdk-test-target-setup-x64-fails-when-run-on-windows-7-computer?forum=wdk) link its said that windows 7 have bugs regarding WDK Test Target Setup.

I have posted similar question on microsoft forum but no answers yet and this is just the first step.

Comment: Do u need a driver that runs on both win7 and Win 10? And why do u need Os loader?

Answer (score 0):

I reached till here. using this source  https://www.codemetrix.net/windows-kernel-debugging-setup/

**Environment**
Enable VT-d in bios to install 64 bit OS

windows 10 do not need license, windows 8.1 needs so use this windows 10.

Windows 8.1 64 bit host.

windows 10 64 bit target inside virtualbox.

Once windows 10 is installed, go to Devices -> Run insert guest additions CD image. After this enable drag and drop.

Install visual studio 2017 on host. All tools will be installed with it.

Path for 64 bit WinDbg

**C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Kits\Debugging Tools for Windows (X64)**

Find WinDbg (usually above path) and get a VirtualBox image of your target - called “Debuggee” - installed in VirtualBox. Then open the virtual machine configuration and activate a serial port (COM1).

Important part is serial connection between host and target.

In the “Serial Ports” configuration select **Portnumber COM1**, **Port mode “Host Pipe”** and choose a **name for the path**, i.e. **\.\pipe\windebugpipe**. (You can replace ‘windebugpipe’ by another name here but keep it consistent in the following steps and make sure you keep the \.\pipe\ prefix.) **Leave the box “Connect to existing pipe/socket” unchecked**.

Now, on the Host, also open a command prompt as Administrator and fire up WinDbg.

**Windbg -b -k com:pipe,port=\.\pipe\windebugpipe,resets=0,reconnect**

Note that the port parameter should match your path in the VM settings.
WinDbg is now waiting for a connection to the debuggee.

Restart the virtual machine. The VM should connect to your debugger. The debugger will probably already kick in in the boot process and stop the VM while windows is still starting up, so don’t be irritated if it stops loading. Press “g” and Enter in the Debugger command prompt to let Windows continue booting. If the debugger doesn’t kick in the first time, try to reboot the VM

**Figuring out this**
In my case debugger is busy in processing this command and VM is stopped halfway. So figuring out what more can be done.

Waited 20 mins until windows 10 VM boots up. On WinDbg command prompt I see this 
**KDTARGET: Refreshing KD connection**

Maybe connection is lost.